# How to pass a string from one view to another in tab based app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a tab based application having 4 tabs and 4 views respective to these tabs.
I have a string in first view and when I printing this string in second view it printing null.

In first view.h

```
NSString *dateString;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *dateString;
```

In first view.m

```
@synthesize dateString;
dateString=button6.titleLabel.text;
NSLog(@"dateString:%@",dateString);
```

In second view.h

```
NSString *dateString;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *dateString;
```

In second view.m

```
@synthesize dateString;

- (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"dateString:%@",self.dateString);
}
```

Comment: How about some code on how you are storing and printing that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **NSString** variable in Application **delegate** class and set the **Property** and make **synthesize** that variable.

And set the **@""** (blank) value in **applicationDidFinishLaunching** method.

For Example - my variable name is str, then initialize str in applicationDidFinishLaunching like `self.str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];`

And now you can use it in any **tab** **view** and set the value as per your require.

More code

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    NSString *baseURL;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *baseURL;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize baseURL;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    self.baseURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [baseURL release];

    [window release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**ViewController1.h**

```
@class AppDelegate;

@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}

@end
```

**ViewController1.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController1.h"

@implementation ViewController1

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSLog(@"value - %@",appDelegate.baseURL); // Here you can set or get the value.
}
```

Comment: by doing like this its showing error: request for member 'dateString' in something not a structure or union and 
'dateString' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: in both view controller, in first where I am setting its value and in second view controller where I am printing its value.

Comment: @Love Chetu: Its printing correct value, but what is happening is that when I changed the in view1 and switch to view2 it reads previous value and if will switch again then in 2nd time it reads changed value, means if I continuously change value in view1 and switch to view2 it always reads previous changed value not currently changed value.

Comment: @Archana, How you change the value please mention in comments or mail me.

Comment: If you want the changes in one place affect the other, use an `NSMutableString` and alter it. What you're doing now is changing the object that view1's `dateString` is pointing to.

Comment: @Love Chetu: ok, plz give me ur mail id.

Comment: @Archana, my email id - chetanbhalala@gmail.com

Comment: @Archana, this is bad practice.  It is the quick and dirty way to pass around values, but now you end up with highly coupled classes.

Answer (score 2):

Add your view controllers as properties for the application delegate (if the app is a relatively simple design).

Then you can reference the properties of the second view controller from the first view controller, by way of the app delegate. (One such property could be the string you want the second VC to copy or retain.)

Comment: You might want to post some code, and perhaps we can help debug it with you. Right now, there's simply not enough information to help you.

Comment: Where is the code for where you set the value of the second view controller's `dateString`?

Comment: I don't want to set the value of dateString in second view controller, I just want to check some condition on the basis of its value which is set in first view controller.

Comment: Then you want a reference to the first controller in the second. Do this when you instantiate the first and second controllers, or keep a data model class separate of your view controllers that has the string value.

Answer (score 0):

it may not be the best answer.but creating a string variable in the appdelgate and passing the variable to this from the first view and fetching it from the second view works for me

Answer (score 0):

Really, did we lose focus of MVC and the most awesome of abilities that is easy to do in iPhone Development?

How about a delegate?

```
@protocol ViewOneDelegate
- (void)getStringVariable;
@end

@interface ViewOneModel : NSObject
{
    NSString* _stringVariable;
    id<ViewOneDelegate> _theDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ViewOneDelegate> theDelegate;

@end
```

Assign a controller to be the delegate for the ViewOneModel.

Comment: ok, But sorry I couldn't understood the above, will you please explain more,,,so that I can implement it, or according to my code plz write your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution, but not the best one, Create a global variable, and just use that.

Header

```
  extern NSString *GlobalString;
    @interface GlobalVariables : NSObject {
    }

@end
```

implementation

```
#import "GlobalVariables.h"

@implementation GlobalVariables
 NSString *GlobalString;
@end
```

And now to have access to the variable just import the header in the file you want to use.
You'll probably want to check if it's initiated before you use it.

Comment: The class here is a red herring. Unlike C++, statics/globals do not live in a class' namespace if they are defined within the class' interface.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan , i know it's not the right way of doing it but it works for me. I would appreciate it if you could give me a tutorial link to the right way of creating variables that are available in all the projects, global variables. Thanks

Comment: No, I mean the class has no bearing on how you use the variable *at all*. It looks like it's connected to the variable but it's living in a parallel dimension to it.

Comment: A yes sorry. now i understood, i copy pasted from an old project that's why the class is in there. Sorry still working on my english skills.